# Material UI Pagination Ranges : I have two ellipsis instead of one

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I want to achieve a result like this : [image]

Actual result :
[image]

I have two ellipsis instead of one,
I have tried to play with  siblingCount={-4} and  boundaryCount={2} but i didn't have the desired result can any one help me I am Beginner.

```
export default function PaginationRanges() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2}>
      <Pagination
        count={10}
        defaultPage={1}
        page={1}
        siblingCount={-4}
        boundaryCount={2}
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/paginationranges-material-demo-forked-7hbs7?file=/demo.js:0-415)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `react-paginate` instead. i also have a requirement of showing

`1 2 3 4 ... 8`

but material UI always starts with

`1 2 3 4 5 ... 8`

`react-paginate` has props like `range` with which you can configure the position of ellipsis.